# Spring-MVC forms on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, forms, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a form using the Spring Framework, but according
to this (http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/
browse_thread/thread/d93fd7385bf85bf7), I need to override initBinder.
Well, I think I did that and it still doesn't work.

My jsp (priceincreasejsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"
isELIgnored="false" session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/
form" %>
<form:form method="post" commandName="priceIncrease">
   Increase (%): <form:input path="percentage"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form:form>
```

myapp-servlet.xml has the following:

```
<bean name="/priceincrease.htm"
class="myapp.web.PriceIncreaseFormController">
   <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
   <property name="commandName" value="priceIncrease"/>
   <property name="commandClass" value="myapp.service.PriceIncrease"/
>
   <property name="validator">
       <bean class="myapp.service.PriceIncreaseValidator"/>
   </property>
   <property name="formView" value="priceincrease"/>
   <property name="successView" value="success.htm"/>
   <property name="productManager" ref="productManager" />
</bean>
```

PriceIncrease.java:

```
public class PriceIncrease implements Serializable {
    private Integer percentage;

    public void setPercentage(Integer i) {
        percentage = i;
    }

    public Integer getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }
}
```

PriceIncreaseFormController.java:

```
public class PriceIncreaseFormController extends SimpleFormController
{
   private ProductManager productManager;

   public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)  throws
ServletException {
       PriceIncrease priceIncrease = (PriceIncrease) command;
       Integer increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
       productManager.increasePrice(increase);
       return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
   }

   public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request)
{
       binder.registerCustomEditor(PriceIncrease.class, new
PriceIncreaseEditor());
       binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, 
           new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, true)); // use this instead?
   }

   public void setProductManager() {...}
   public ProductManager getProductManager {...}
}
```

Finally, PriceIncreaseEditor.java: (this is probably wrong..)

```
public class PriceIncreaseEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

   @Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
       Integer increase = new Integer(text);
       super.setValue(increase);
   }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag
doStartTag: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
(java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
       at
java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:
355)
       at
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
567)
       at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:
549)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:
45)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1311)
       at
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findEditorByConvention(BeanUtils.java:
368)
       at
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getCustomEditor(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:
110)
       at
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:
87)
       at
org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:
230)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:
120)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
172)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
192)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
158)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
145)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
136)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:
120)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:
379)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:
139)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:
90)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:
77)
       at
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.priceincrease_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(priceincrease_jsp.java:
149)
       at
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.priceincrease_jsp._jspService(priceincrease_jsp.java:
82)
       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:
511)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:
390)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:
216)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:
182)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:
765)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:
418)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:
240)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:
258)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:
1174)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:
901)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:
809)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:
571)
       at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:
501)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:
511)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
       at
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:
97)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:
35)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
       at
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:
43)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:
388)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:
216)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:
182)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:
765)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:
418)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:
238)
       at
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:
152)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:
542)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection
$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:
76)
       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:
135)
       at
com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:
261)
       at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime
$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8495)
       at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime
$6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:8493)
       at
com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:
24)
       at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:
435)
       at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:
572)
       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable
$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:
688)
       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext
$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:
326)
       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext
$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:
318)
       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext
$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
       at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
1110)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I've been pretty stuck for a while now... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleFormController.initBinder()` [takes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html) `(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder)` while your `initBinder()` takes arguments in the opposite order.

So you haven't overridden it.  Try switching the order of your arguments.  And whenever you intend to override anything, put `@Override` on it so that the compiler can catch mistakes like this one for you.

Comment: This was one of many problems. I eventually got it to work. Thanks!