# Spring MVC and "big forms"

Tags: java, forms, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

It's a really simple question.

I would like to know what's the best practice for submitting a *huge* html form to a Spring MVC @Controller (huge = more than 20 fields / complex fields as list and so on...)

I'm a little bit confused because somebody use this approach (from the official examples):

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/users" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ModelAndView saveUser(Locale locale, @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            logger.error("Errori form:: " + result.getErrorCount());

        } else {

            logger.info("Utente salvato");
            userService.saveUser(user);

        }
        ...
        return mav;
    }
```

and some others use the more complex SimpleFormController this way:
[Spring-MVC forms on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951438/spring-mvc-forms-on-gae)

I surely do prefer the first way but I'm worried I will have to create many "FormBeans", useless DTOs.

Can you explain me differences and give me advices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this example you purposed is doing is using Spring validation. I think that you should look at spring manual or some help, as it is very basic, but the general idea is that Spring is validates the form for you.

First, you have to create a Pojo (create a Class with all the inputs from the form, with getters and setters).

Then, you have to use spring forms, which are slightly different to normal forms. The basic idea is that you map an object (User in your case) to the form. And then, each of the inputs, is mapped to a field of the Pojo.

After that, you add the validation to the Pojo, with annotations.

```
@Size(max = 10)
private String name;
```

For example, this annotation Size indicates that field name must be 10 chars as max.
This validations, are checked with the annotation @Valid.

Then, when hasErrors is called, you can get if the form has errors.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help but.... this is not a complete answer. Can you explain me what's the difference with the other solution? Why should I rather use SimpleFormController?

Comment: Honestly I never used SimpleFormController, so I cannot tell you about it. Also I tried instantiating it on Spring Source and it is marked as deprecated. If you look the link you posted, it is basically the same, the difference are the mappings on the controllers. onSubmit on SimpleFormController does not have RequestMapping (I asume it is done automatically?) and this controller you posted it does. Also it is similar because what you do in SimpleFormController ir casting command to another object (user), and here it is taken directly. I suggest to look at both examples carefully.